# Unbound variable in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a toy singleton in python to learn the ins and outs of the language and am running into a problem with how python works.  I declare the class like this

```
class ErrorLogger:
  # Singleton that provides logging to a file  
  instance = None

  def getInstance():
    # Our singleton "constructor"
    if instance is None :
      print "foo"
```

when I call it with

```
log = ErrorLogger.getInstance()
```

I get

```
 File "/home/paul/projects/peachpit/src/ErrorLogger.py", line 7, in getInstance
    if instance is None :
 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'instance' referenced before assignment
```

What is going on here, shouldn't instance be statically assigned Null?  What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: You can use `@staticmethod` or `@clsmethod`, both of which are described very well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call it with `ErrorLogger` prefix as it is a static variable.

```
class ErrorLogger:
  # Singleton that provides logging to a file  
  instance = None

  @staticmethod
  def getInstance():
    # Our singleton "constructor"
    if ErrorLogger.instance is None :
      print "foo"
```

Comment: You can also use @classmethod, the differences are subtle but still there.

Comment: An advantage of `@classmethod` is that you'd get the class as an argument to the method, so you could use it to grab the singleton directly: `@classmethod def getInstance(cls): if cls.instanece is None: ...`